# How does asynchronous call work in AngularJS 1.X? $Http call not returning value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, asynchronous

I have the following function named `getvalue`. It is inside an AngularJS module together with a controller. I am trying to call this function on click event invoking another function in a controller.(I hope I am clear)

**function:**

```
  function getvalue(Data, $http) {
            var value=undefined;
           $http({
                url: /myurl,
                method: "GET",
                params: {
                    tmp: Data.tmp,
                    pressure: Data.pressure               
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {            
                value=parseFloat(  console.log(data));//console working here
               return value;
            });
        return value;
        }
```

**Code inside Controller**

```
 value= getvalue(formData, $http );
        alert(value);//undefined here. Seems like value is never changed.
```

I have not getting the value on alert but console is printing the value. I need help if possible for two issues.

1. **How can I change the value from inside success and return to controller?**
2. **Is there any way that I don't have to inject $Http from controller to function?** 
   -----It would be nice if I can do that for unit testing.

Comment: You need to use a callback. You can't `return` from an async call...

Comment: @tymeJV oh okay! Any references?

Comment: remove second `return value;`. After check please

Comment: @Vineet it doesn't work. I think the problem is that I am not using callbacks.

Comment: @Vineet how can async call will work by just removing `return value`?

Comment: @PankajParkar, A function always have a `return` value. I suppose compiler will wait the return value of this function. OP already has been returning value before getting output from async call. So I thought it might work.

Comment: @Vineet no bro..you should have read how async call & promises works ..and why you are pulling compiler here..its related to ajax request..he should return a promise rather than returning a value only..take a look at mine answer

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks for sharing your thoughts. I will definiately read more on async call

Comment: @Vineet read my answer..how it could be do-able..

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks bro :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would ideally want to pull the $http service out of the controller and make a factory to do those calls.

in the factory have a function that accepts the data you are wanting to send and have it return the promise back to the controller

something like this

Repo

```
app.factory("fooRepo", ["$http", function($http){
    return {
        getValue: function(data){
            return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/myUrl"
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Serivce

```
app.factory("foo", ["$q", "fooRepo", function($q, fooRepo){
    return {
        getValue: function(data){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            fooRepo.getValue(data)
            .success(function(results){
                //do some work
                deferred.resolve(results);
            })
            .error(function(error){
                // do some work
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

here is the controller

```
app.controller("fooCtrl", ["foo", function(foo){
    foo.getValue(dataHere)
        .then(function(results){
            // do something here
        });
}]);
```

[Added Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1CgLJgnmjt3sv2caP938)

Comment: why you created extra promise..it shouldn't be there

Comment: to keep the controller from have to do any kind of logic, thats actually mixture of my repository and the service. by resolving the promise in the service i can do any kind of work on the data i need to and then pass back a promise to the controller

Comment: @Teliren I have a question again. In this case Angular is complaining that  `foo.getValue is not a function` any solution for that?

Comment: @DineshDevkota added plunkr for you

Comment: @Teliren Well thanks for your effort. However, I am trying to call `foo.getValue` inside a  (Controller) function that is invoked by `ng-click` in a button and got the error.

Comment: @Teliren well works here. http://plnkr.co/edit/i0eFF56ukv2cH0td9l4j?p=preview IDK, what is the issue with my app. Thanks for your answer. You deserve the answer to be accepted.

Comment: @DineshDevkota If you can put your actual code in a plnkr ill take a look at it

Comment: @Teliren I have my scenario here. http://plnkr.co/edit/i0eFF56ukv2cH0td9l4j?p=preview Thanks man.

Comment: @DineshDevkota on your controller dependencies scope and foo are not in the same order in both places

Answer (score 1):

As you are calling a method which is doing async call, you must return promise from there as you don't know when data will get back from the ajax. On success of that ajax you should update your variable. Outside of ajax function you will get undefined value because value is returned in async manner.

**Function**

```
 function getvalue(Data) {
      var value=undefined;
      return $http({
          url: /myurl,
          method: "GET",
          params: {
              tmp: Data.tmp,
              pressure: Data.pressure               
            }
      })
}
```

**Controller**

```
 getvalue(formData).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {            
      console.log(data);//you will get data here
 });
```

Comment: how would you inject $http inside that function?

Comment: Angular conplains `$http not defined` if you are not going to inject it to function from controller.

Comment: @DineshDevkota you should add `$http` inside your `controller`/`service` wherever you are using this `getvalue` method..

Comment: @DineshDevkota does it helped you..?

Comment: @DineshDevkota what else is remaining?

Comment: I intended to create unit testable functions. Out of luck, may be!

Answer (score 0):

A $http-Request is async. That means that alert will be called before the .success(..) callback is executed.

You can see a result on the console because it reflects changes made after the call of console.log().

Calling alert(value); in the .success()-Callback will shield the desired result.

Answer (score -2):

Replace:

```
 }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {            
     value=parseFloat(  console.log(data));//console working here
     return value;
});
```

with:

```
 }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {            
     alert(parseFloat(data));
});
```

Comment: Read question bud! I am asking to pass value to controller. I am not trying to alert there!

Comment: ~Dinesh Devotka sorry then, my bad. 
~Pankaj Parkar As I know succes is called when we get async result, same with .error

From jQuery.ajax() : 
"success
Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified; "