# Jasmine unit test AngularJS factory with two dependencies ($http and another factory returning promise)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework for custom applications. In the process, I am trying to write Unit test for the factory `datastoreServices` which has a dependency on `DomainService` and `$http`. I am kind a confused on the implementation of Jasmine Unit tests.

My factories are as follows.

```
app.factory("datastoreServices", ["$http", function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function(data, DomainService) {
            return $http.post(DomainService.host + 'factor', data);
        }
    };
}]);

app.factory('DomainService', function() { //here
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
        return {
            host: 'http://10.0.2.2:7001/'
        }
    }
    return {
        host: 'http://localhost:7001/'
    }
})
```

And my unit test skeleton is as follows. It has two dependencies so, couldn't figure out how to proceed. This is what I got so far for in unit test file.

```
describe(
        'datastoreServices',
        function() {
            beforeEach(module('Myapp'));
            describe('getData'),
                function() {
                    it("Should return correct values", inject(function(datastoreServices, DomainService, $httpBackend) {
                            expect(datastoreServices.getData(httpBackend.. /***something here!**/ )
                                .toEqual("2.2");
                            }))
                    }
```

I have very little knowledge on mocking and stuffs. Can someone help me test that factory `datastoreServices`. The following things are to be tested:

- **Is Http post making correct calls?**
- **Is the function returning correct promise?**

Here is the similar scenario of app in **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1CgLJgnmjt3sv2caP938?p=info)**.

Idk, if I am asking too much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand the problem. There are tons of examples mocking $http. So what is so special here? BTW where is the relationship to ionic?? Another question: is your app working, only struggling with the test?

Comment: Well, yes you are right that- there are lots of examples of mocking $http. However, I am not just testing $http but also the controller that contain it. In describe section I have two different test scenario. Ionic is used but that is not very relevant to the question. And Yes, the application is fully functional it is just wanted to have test methods for each function. The senario of the app is added as in `plnker` http://plnkr.co/edit/1CgLJgnmjt3sv2caP938. How would you test each functions there.

Comment: factory `foo` is only useless boilerplate code and can be eliminated completely. The controller is not a useful controller. You should provide more realistic examples so it's fun to test your code ;-)

Comment: @hgoebl the problem arises after the implementation of code here. See the explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548385/how-to-return-a-value-to-controller-from-function-with-asynchronous-http-service/31548686#31548686

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key principles are:

- $http is mocked during testing, meaning that your server is not being actually called during your test execution
- you must use $httpBackend in order to assert http calls and mock server response https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend
- you can easily inject or mock any dependencies needed for your test

Here's an example based on your OP code:

```
    describe('datastoreServices', function() {

    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

    // get a reference to the $httpBackend mock and to the service to test, and create a mock for DomainService
    var $httpBackend, datastoreServices, DomainService;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _datastoreServices_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        datastoreServices = _datastoreServices_;
        DomainService = function() {
            return {
                host: 'http://localhost:7001/'
            };
        };
    }));

    // after each test, this ensure that every expected http calls have been realized and only them
    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });


    it('calls http backend to get data', function() {
        var data = {foo: 'bar'};

        // write $http expectation and specify a mocked server response for the request
        // see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend
        $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost:7001/factor', data).respond(201, {bar: 'foo'});

        var returnedData;
        datastoreServices.getData(data, DomainService).success(function(result) {
            // check that returned result contains
            returnedData = result;
            expect(returnedData).toEqual({bar: 'foo'});
        });

        // simulate server response
        $httpBackend.flush();

        // check that success handler has been called
        expect(returnedData).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it is quite not clear to me as it doesn't have `it` block or function to flush out messages that each unit test is passed. I tried surround each `expect` with `it` and it doesn't seem to be working. Can you clarify on that?

Comment: I am getting `datastoreServices getData encountered a declaration exception. $httpBackend is undefined`

Comment: you are right, change the second describe() to it(), it should solve the errors you have

Comment: @DineshDevkota did this help you ?

Comment: `TypeError: currentSpec is null` is what I am getting not sure from where.