# I can't access property of object from .factory AngularJS 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a simple AngularJS service with .factory() called **$getUser** that gets data from **users.json**:

```
{
    "john": {
        "name": "John",
        "address": "New York"
    },

    "bob": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "address": "Boston"
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this data in **mainController**:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.factory('$getUser', ['$http', function($http){
    var users = {};

    $http.get('users.json').then(
        function(response) {
            users.data = response.data;
        }
    );

    return users;
}])

.controller('mainController', ['$getUser', function($getUser){

    // I can access whole $getUser object
    console.log($getUser);

    // but when I want to access $getUser.data it gives me 'undefined'
    console.log($getUser.data);

}]);
```

When I want to [**console**](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/PgZMQE/) whole **$getUser** object, it works, but I am not able to access **$getUser.data** property. Why?

Comment: In my guess, you don't need to use `data` object. because may be your factory have not data object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does asynchronous call work in AngularJS 1.X? $Http call not returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548385/how-does-asynchronous-call-work-in-angularjs-1-x-http-call-not-returning-value)

Answer (score 1):

Create factory as:

```
app.factory('$getUser', ['$http',  function($http) {

  var factory = {               
    query: function () {                
       return $http.get('users.json').then(function (response) {
          return response.data;                            
               }, function (result) {
                   alert("Error: No data returned");
              });             
            }
       }       
        return factory;
}]);
```

So you can call it as:

```
$scope.data = $getUser.query()
```

<kbd>[Simple demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xh1wxLwa/)</kbd>

---

However I suggest to return promise and resolve it in controller

The common approach to load JSON is:

```
app.factory('Items', ['$http',
    function($http) {

        return {
            getJson: function(url) {
                var ItemsJson = $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
                return ItemsJson;
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

and Usage:

```
 var jsonPromise = Items.getJson('jsonData/someJSON.json');
 jsonPromise.then(function (_response) {
 // ...
 }, function (error) {
     console.error(error);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])

    .factory('$getUser', ['$http', function($http) {
      var users = {};
      return {
        getData: function() {
          return $http({
            url: 'users.json',
            method: 'GET'
          })
        }
      }
    }])

    .controller('mainController', ['$getUser', function($getUser) {

      // I can access whole $getUser object
      console.log($getUser);

      // but when I want to access $getUser.data it gives me 'undefined'
      console.log($getUser.data);
      $getUser.getData().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.data);
      });

    }]);
```

[Fiddle Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7VuG9ffMuFtRMueE7kKn?p=preview)

Comment: Now also he getting the same issue

Comment: Try not using "$" when defining factories; user-defined factories do not usually use it (best practice).

Comment: @RamsingNadeem i just corrected the question code. thanx for suggestion :-)

Comment: My apology; I thought I was commenting on the question rather than an answer.